# Erlang Types Specifications

Tags: erlang

I recently read the source code of couch-db, I find this type definition which i don't understand:

```
-type branch() :: {Key::term(), Value::term(), Tree::term()}.
-type path() :: {Start::pos_integer(), branch()}.
-type tree() :: [branch()].
```

I did read [Erlang doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html), But what is the meaning of **Start**, **Key**, **Value** and **Tree**? From  what i understand, they are Erlang variables! I didn't find any information about this in [Erlang doc](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html).

Answer (score 7):

`Start` etc. are just descriptive names for the respective parts of the terms, to make it easier for humans to read the type definition. They have nothing to do with actual variable names.

(Side note: Unfortunately, even in OTP R14B, `edoc` still does not read `-type` and `-spec` for generating its HTML documentation - it uses the old `@type` and `@spec` instead.)

**Update:** The [official docs on `-type` and `-spec`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html). More things to search for are the word **success typing** and the manuals for **dialyzer** and **typer**.

Comment: Page you are looking for: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html